# Got error in Crystal Report formula

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports, report

presently i have a formula field which does the sum of particular field.now i want to perform condition on that.i want sum of AmountPending column only when SeatNo column is not blank.

```
if {DataTable1.SeatNo != ""} 
then Sum ({DataTable1.AmountPending})
else
```

Comment: if {DataTable1.SeatNo} <> "" then
  Sum ({DataTable1.AmountPending})
else   do nothing;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if totext({DataTable1.SeatNo}) <> '' 

then 
  Sum ({DataTable1.AmountPending})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not(Isnull({DataTable1.SeatNo})) Then
  Sum ({DataTable1.AmountPending})
Else
  0
```